# Data folder not opening in File Explorer

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, ddms

A very brief question: I'm trying to locate my SQLite database in DDMS by navigating to /data/data/com.application.package/databases/database_name. I can locate the data folder in my File Explorer, but I apparently cannot open it to reveal its contents. This seems like a very absurd and minor problem, but I do not understand the cause of it. If anyone has faced a similar scenario, I'd really appreciate any input. Just to clarify, its not only the data folder that isn't opening. All the folders that have an arrow next to them indicating that they have subfolders/files do not open to reveal their contents (which is perplexing)!

P.S. The app is working fine on my phone and seems to store data well. I just cannot open the data folder to see the database file!

Comment: Have you installed the Eclipse SQLiteBrowser plugin? It requires the database extension to be **.db** (mind the casing)

Comment: I would like to be able to access the database files for all users of this application that I'm making. Would that be possible?

Comment: Yes your app can access that folder. You should add to your app a file explorer activity and you are done. There are several examples on the web. That folder is private to your app so other apps have no access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have permissions to view the directory contents.

To verify from the command line:

```
adb shell
cd data
ls <-- Probably yeilds opendir failed, Permission denied
```

If you can't access it via adb, DDMS won't do much better.  If you're phone is rooted, you can do

```
adb root
adb remount
```

and probably have better luck.

Comment: It says the term adb is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program.. :/

Comment: @user3694391 whoa, I'm not sure what to say about that one.  How are you deploying your app without adb installed?

Comment: I installed the Android SDK. Doesn't it include everything, includeing adb?

Comment: Yes, you may just need to navigate to the sdk/platform-tools directory (where adb is located) and run "adb shell" etc. from there.

Comment: I did that. It now says 'The command adb was not found but does exist in the current location. If you trust this command, instead type ".\adb" '. But typing ".\adb root" gives the comment "adbd cannot run as root in production builds". What's even happening here?

Comment: Okay, so you found adb and it seems to be working; that's good.  The comment you're getting indicates you do not have root privileges on your device.  Try the first block of commands above, "adb shell" etc. and let me know what you get from that "ls" command.

Comment: I typed .\adb shell and the commands above. I got exactly what you predicted: opendir failed. Permission denied. 
How do I move forward and resolve this? 

(P.S. Thank you immensely for your willingness and time in helping me through this. :))

Comment: I wish I could be more help at this point, but I'm not sure how to gain access without permissions.  Perhaps the app managing the db can move it to the sdcard so you can view it.